# UIImagePickerController with Cocos2D 2.0

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I want use UIImagePickerController, and I found this example

Added to .h

```
@interface MenuScene : CCLayer <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    UIWindow *window;
    UIImage *newImage;
}
```

Added to .m

```
-(void)pickPhoto:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType{    
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = sourceType;
    picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    [picker presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:nil];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:picker.view];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    newImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [picker.view removeFromSuperview];
    [picker release];
    CCSprite *imageFromPicker = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:newImage.CGImage key:@"ImageFromPicker"];
}
```

I try to call `[self pickcPhoto:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]` and it crash at `[picker presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:nil];` with message

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modal view controller on itself. Presenting controller is .
'

I'm using Cocos2d v2 testing on iOS 6, I will be thankful for any advice.

Comment: This is self explanatory as you call the _[**picker** presentViewController: **picker** animated:NO completion:nil];_ (see the bold part). You can't call picker to present picker(itself ie same type of uiviewcontroller same class i mean) modally as both are same LOL :)

Comment: hehe.. right totaly miss it. But why in all examples they use it in that way?

Comment: will you please give me the link which example you follow so I can explain that also :)

Comment: here you are http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/5734#post-34228

Comment: Yep you are right that code shows it but read the below comments from other users they have also faced problems with this and they also provide some work around that will help you to understand further more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that at this moment, cocos have some issue with iOS6 and portrain orientation. ImagePickerController works only in portrain so that's crash origin. I will be monitoring this case and update when something will change.

Answer (score 2):

Change the code as below just change the line with `Edit in this line` comment or can copy past that line

```
-(void)pickPhoto:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType{    
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.sourceType = sourceType;
    picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:nil]; //Edit in this line
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:picker.view];
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    newImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; //Edit in this line
    [picker.view removeFromSuperview];
    [picker release];
    CCSprite *imageFromPicker = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:newImage.CGImage key:@"ImageFromPicker"];
}
```

Comment: Sadly `Instance method '-presentViewController:animated:completion:' not found`

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIViewController with a property of UIImagePickerViewController and load that modally.

Check this really useful Apple example http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2